# Adding an Access table with an AutoNumber Primary Key via ADOX

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am trying to add a new table with a primary key and want to set its 'AutoIncrement' property to True. Here is what I am doing:

```
Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog
Dim tbl As New ADOX.Table
Dim col As New ADOX.Column
Dim cnn As Object
Dim dbs As Database
Dim DataSource As String

DataSource = "\\spdb\depts\Msg_be.accdb"

Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
  "Data Source=" & DataSource & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=psWrD; "

Set dbs = OpenDatabase(DataSource, False, False, "MS Access;PWD=psWrD")
cat.ActiveConnection = cnn

tbl.Name = "tblMsg"

tbl.Columns.Append "MsgID", adInteger
tbl.Keys.Append "PrimaryKey", adKeyPrimary, "MsgID"
tbl.Columns.Item("MsgID").Properties("AutoIncrement") = True
cat.Tables.Append tbl
```

However, I get this error:

```
Run-time error '3265':
Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.
```

at line:

```
tbl.Columns.Item("MsgID").Properties("AutoIncrement") = True
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code, borrowing heavily from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa155430%28v=office.10%29.aspx), seems to do the trick:

```vbs
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cat As ADOX.Catalog, tbl As ADOX.Table
Dim col As ADOX.Column, key As ADOX.key

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;"
Set cat = New ADOX.Catalog
cat.ActiveConnection = con

Set tbl = New ADOX.Table
tbl.Name = "tblMsg"
cat.Tables.Append tbl

Set col = New ADOX.Column
Set col.ParentCatalog = cat
col.Name = "MsgID"
col.Type = adInteger
col.Properties("AutoIncrement") = True
col.Properties("Seed") = CLng(1)
col.Properties("Increment") = CLng(1)
tbl.Columns.Append col

Set key = New ADOX.key
key.Name = "PRIMARY"
key.Type = adKeyPrimary
key.Columns.Append "MsgID"
tbl.Keys.Append key
```

Key points:

- The "AutoNumber-ness" is a function of the column (field), not the key.
- Setting the `.ParentCatalog` object property allows ADOX to recognize that `col` is an Access column and therefore can have "AutoIncrement", "Seed", and "Increment" Properties, all three of which combine to form an `AutoNumber` field.

Comment: The version of ADOX.Column that I am using in 2020 says that col.Properties(x) is read-only. This is legacy code, but I needed to be able to support it. I'll go a different route, but wanted others to know this might not still work.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably figure out how to revise your ADOX approach to get what you want.  However, since you can open a working ADO connection to the target db, I think it should be simpler to just use that connection to execute an `ALTER TABLE` statement which adds the autonumber *MsgID* field to your table.

I tested this approach in Access 2007 and it successfully added the autonumber field to my *tblMsg* table.  (However I had to alter the ADO connection properties in order to connect to my db file.)

```vb
Dim cnn As Object
Dim DataSource As String
Dim strSql As String

DataSource = "\\spdb\depts\Msg_be.accdb"
Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
  "Data Source=" & DataSource & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=psWrD; "
strSql = "ALTER TABLE tblMsg ADD COLUMN MsgID COUNTER PRIMARY KEY;"
Debug.Print strSql
cnn.Execute strSql
```

Comment: This may feel a bit "hacky" versus creating the column "correctly" in ADOX, but it was a lot easier than any other option that I came across. Bravo!